# Mongocxx compiling issue on windows

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm trying to compile a simple .cpp using the mongocxx lib. This is my code string_tests.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace mongocxx;

int main() {

    instance instance{}; // This should be done only once.
    cout << "hello" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I already have built the mongocxx library, I have everyting on C:\MinGW\thirdParty, this is the structure:

- C:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-c-driver\bin
- C:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-c-driver\lib
- C:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-c-driver\include
- C:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\bin
- C:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\lib
- C:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\include  (<-- here are the
  \bsoncxx\v_noabi and \mongocxx\v_noabi folders)

And I also added the bin folders to my PATH environment variable

The [Mongo documentation](https://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/#compiling) said that I can compile my file with the next:

g++ --std=c++17 L:\dev\cpp\tests\string_tests.cpp -o L:\dev\cpp\tests\string_tests.exe -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\include\mongocxx\v_noabi -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi -LC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\lib -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx

I tried to compile my .cpp, it give me the next error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmX2SEM.o:string_tests.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8mongocxx7v_noabi8instanceC1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmX2SEM.o:string_tests.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8mongocxx7v_noabi8instanceD1Ev'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmX2SEM.o:string_tests.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8mongocxx7v_noabi8instanceD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried it adding the bson libraries and included paths and I'm getting the same problem:

g++ --std=c++17 L:\dev\cpp\tests\string_tests.cpp -o L:\dev\cpp\tests\string_tests.exe -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\include\mongocxx\v_noabi -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-c-driver\include\libbson-1.0 -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-c-driver\include\libmongoc-1.0 -LC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\lib -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx -LC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-c-driver\lib -lbson-1.0 -lmongoc-1.0

I used this mongocxx driver installation in another project and it's working perfectly (I'm using it in a Unreal Engine CPP project which have a very different compilation settings, and it's working there, I just want to simplify the process compiling it in a simple .cpp file for fast tests).

Can anyone tell me what am I doing worng? Thanks in advance

Comment: The order of the libraries are important. The linker goes through the list only once, so if a later lib needs something from an earlier one, it will not go back and retry that,

Comment: But I compiling it in the same order that the documentation said:

```g++ --std=c++17 L:\dev\cpp\tests\string_tests.cpp -o L:\dev\cpp\tests\string_tests.exe -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\include\mongocxx\v_noabi -IC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi -LC:\MinGW\thirdParty\mongo-cxx-driver\lib -lmongocxx -lbsoncxx```

BTW I also tried with mingw 32 and 64bits, and the same result. Thanks anyway!